# create table in docx file

Tags: php, asp.net, mysql, docx, phpdoc

I have troubling to write colorful heading of table or colored background of table in docx or doc file for three days but i cant finding the proper solution. I am using a php library [phpdocx](http://www.phpdocx.com) to generate docx files.

Can any one please tell me what i am doing wrong here ?

Here is my code i am trying with :

```
require_once '../../classes/CreateDocx.inc';


    $docx = new CreateDocx();
    //Tables
    $valuesTable = array(
    array(
            'head 1','head 2','head 3','head 4','head 5','head 6','head 7','head 8','head 9','head 10'
        ),
        array(
            11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
        ),
        array(
            21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30
        ),
    );

    $paramsTable = array(
        'border' => 'single',
        'border_sz' => 20,
        'TBLSTYLEval' => 'MediumGrid3-accent5PHPDOCX'
    );

    //$paramsTable = array('TBLSTYLEval' => 'MediumGrid3-accent5PHPDOCX');

    $docx->addTable($valuesTable, $paramsTable);
    ##########################

    $docx->createDocx('example_image');
```

It's generating simple table table without any formatting like border,color etc.

Thanks a lot.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use .Net my friend :) - There is the Open XML SDK wich is very powerful.